# How to read Feign client response header when return is 204

Tags: feign, openfeign

I am using plain feign client. Basically I used swagger to generate client contract from yaml.
I realize that when there is no response object, return type is void. I want to read header value when i receive 204. How do I do that ?

This is how I am creating client

```
  public ApiClient() {
    objectMapper = createObjectMapper();
    apiAuthorizations = new LinkedHashMap<String, RequestInterceptor>();
    feignBuilder = Feign.builder()
                .encoder(new FormEncoder(new JacksonEncoder(objectMapper)))
                .decoder(new JacksonDecoder(objectMapper))
                .logger(new Slf4jLogger());
  }


    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient().setBasePath(basePath);
    apiClient.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    apiClient.getFeignBuilder().client(apacheClient);
    apiClient.getFeignBuilder().options(new Request.Options(connectTimeoutMillis, readTimeoutMillis));
    apiClient.getFeignBuilder().errorDecoder(new MyClientErrorDecoder(apiClient.getObjectMapper(), additionalService));
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        apiClient.getFeignBuilder().logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.FULL);
    }
    
    api = apiClient.buildClient(ApiContract.class);
```

ApiContract looks like this (default-auto generated from swagger)

```
    public interface ApiContract extends ApiClient.Api {
            
          @RequestLine("POST /deleteMe")
          @Headers({
              "Content-Type: application/json",
              "Accept: application/json",
            "X-Request-ID: {xRequestID}",
            "Client-Name: {clientName}",
            "myParam1: {myParam1}",
            "Content-Digest: {contentDigest}",
            "myInput: {myInput}",
            "myInput2: {myInput2}"
          })
          void deleteMe(MyRequestBody body, 
          @Param("xRequestID") UUID xRequestID, 
          @Param("clientName") String clientName, 
          @Param("myParam1") String myParam1, 
          @Param("contentDigest") 
          String contentDigest, 
          @Param("myInput") String myInput, 
          @Param("myInput2") String myInput2);
}
```

if I change from "void" to "Response", MyClientErrorDecoder is not called for 4xx error as it used to be.